# iOS Sharing Extension works on Device but not in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, file-sharing

I had to delete the Sharing Extension I had in my project and start it over from scratch - its working just fine on my iPhone6 now, but its ***not*** showing up in the Simulator - which is very weird.

The **Photos** App in the Simulator for example is unable to see my App. Same goes for the **Settings** App: its not seeing my App (there's no on/off switch there to enable it.)

I know I did everything right - cause its working fine on the iPhone - but its still a drag cause testing it on my iPhone just takes longer than it would on the Simulator.

I'm thinking there's some tiny little setting - some little checkbox I need to check somewhere to get it working in the Simulator again - any ideas?

Comment: Try deleting the app on the simulator and the re-run the app.

Comment: I did. Like 10 times! :-)  I also reset the Simulator - didn't help.

Comment: OK - figured it out: when *I recreated* my Sharing Extension Target, it defaulted to iOS 9.3....  while the App is still set to iOS 9.0 - and I was still running it on the 9.0 Simulator. So while that particular Simulator could support the App, it couldn't support its extension.  Kinda silly - but I'll leave this up as hopefully someone else down the road will benefit from this as yet another thing to be sure and double-check for as you go about your own debugging...